# MySQL database design for Twitter-like timeline

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on an application which requires to show different posts on user's timeline(something like Twitter).

A User's timeline consists of following:

1. Reports which user created
2. Reports which other user created and fall under his/her 'alert location' radius
3. Reports posted by other users which he/she follows (Even if that report does not fall inside 'alert location' radius)
4. Report Shared/Re-tweeted by user he follows (Even if that report does not fall inside 'alert location' radius)
5. Reports which other user created and fall under his/her 'current location' radius when a user is travelling.
6. Follow notification- When someone started following him/her
7. Message notification- When someone sent a message to him/her

**Note:-** Once a report appear in user's timeline then it will not disappear even if user move out of location radius or changes 'alert location'. It will only disappear when it is deleted or flagged as inappropriate.

**Requirement:** I need an optimal DB schema(with SELECT query) so that I can show above mentioned posts on user's timeline.

Here is my current DB structure:

```
Table: users
   UserID (PK)
   email
   password

Table: alert_locations 
   alertLocationID (PK) 
   user_id (FK) 
   latitude 
   longitude 
   radius

Table: followers 
   follower_id (FK) 
   following_id (FK)(follower_id + following_id) = PK

Table: reports 
   reportID (PK) 
   reported_by_id (FK) 
   location 
   latitude 
   longitude 
   parent_id (FK- For retweet relations)
```

Now, taking into the account the above cases of timeline I am thinking of `timeline` table with structure shown below:

```
Table Name: timeline
          timelineID  (PK)
          reference_id  (Can be report_id or follower_id or message_sender_id)
          user_id   (FK) 
          title
          type       (1:For Report, 2:Follow, 3:Message)
```

So, when a report is created, for each user a new row in `timeline` table is inserted who is eligible to view that report. Using this table I can query all types of posts for user's timeline.

But as I see, this approach seems to have scaling issues and it does not look wise to insert 'n' amount of rows in `timeline` table every time a new report is created.

Is there any other better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Apart from no message_sender_id to be found in your schema, most databases were made to handle a little bit of data.  But when designing your application, ask yourself if some kind of archiving might be needed.  The number of times I came across designs where no one did ...   Having a "type" attribute and a reference_id that may reference multiple relations, is not very nice, makes you lose referential integrity, but one needn't be holier than the pope.

Comment: Gotta see the `SELECTs` to judge the schema.

Comment: @RickJames The database is still in design phase so we I don't have SELECT queries. I just need to make sure that what will be optimal design for user's timeline feature.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thank you for the tip. I understand that "type" solution is not efficient. The `timeline` table solution I mentioned is just one of the solution I am thinking about. Sorry, I don't understand when you say "some kind of archiving might be needed" Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "archiving"?

Comment: If you fear "scaling", this will not be necessary in the beginning.  But how far should the timeline go?  Do you need to look back more than 5 years?  If not, you could move that data to an archiving or warehouse database, and delete it from your OLTP system.  This should be studied.  When you delete, does this have consequences for eg. running totals.  It may be quite complex, a reason why the current fast developers don't bother, they'll be long gone when the problem arises.

Comment: @mPareek - _Everyone_ who builds a product the size of Twitter goes through _multiple_ rewrites -- in the schema, in the `SELECTs`, in the user "requirements", etc.  It is folly to think that you can come up with the "right" schema before thinking about hwo the schema will be used.  It is _not_ a serial process; it is an _iterative_ process.

Comment: @RickJames That may be so today, agile and the likes. There was a time when one studied a problem and came up with a solution that satisfied the users for a decade.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - Not in my lifetime.  I do agree that "agile" does not let designers stop and think.  But the old excuse for taking 6 months to 2 years to release a product was that the effort to compile, update the manual, etc, was weeks or months.  Taking the time to "think" can lead to a much more efficient product.  But the "window of opportunity" may close meanwhile.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I see latitude/longitude in the tables; does your team have the experience to know how to make that perform adequately?  ( http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql )

Comment: @RickJames, is the performance question meant for me?  I never really worked in a team.

Answer (score 1):

Details not yet spelled out for the schema:

PKs -- What datatype?  `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes) tops out at 4 billion; think about whether you need to go above that or can shrink the size.

Collations -- For inclusion of Chinese and Emoji, be sure to use `utf8mb4`.

Password -- You should probably *not* store the plain-text password, but rather the encrypted version.

Latitude & Longitude -- How much precision is needed?  What queries will be applied.  This area can lead to some terribly inefficient code.  Your choices *today* impact your ability to even use lat/lng without a major rewrite, especially for your item 5.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices  and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Table: followers -- Does "x follows y" imply that "y follows x"?  The answer to this has an impact all the way back to the table definition.

"reference_id  (Can be report_id or follower_id or message_sender_id)" -- This is *not* easy to implement.  You may have to re-think the requirements.  Ponder whether to do it as 3 tables that are `UNIONed` together.

If you are talking about "massive scale", you will need to allow for "sharding".  I recommend postponing that until later -- *but plan for a major rewrite in the near future*.

If things will be "deleted", will they be "soft" or "hard" deletes or some form of "archiving".  If the quantity is small, this question does not matter; if it is large, it impacts performance and may resort to Partitioning, which is a big schema change.

For performance, consider turning off FKs for production, but keeping them in development.  Be sure to keep the indexes that are implicitly created for FKs.

Etc.

Comment: PKs are `INT UNSIGNED` , Collations is `utf8mb4` ,  Password are hashed. 
Latitude & Longitude -- Thank you for the tip w'll check that out.
followers -- It only imply "x follows y"